# process specific field given by the user bash

Tags: bash, shell, input, awk, field

So the user gives me three inputs ID COLUMN VALUE. I want to replace the field in the line  column  with the value . I tried using awk like this

```
awk -F '|' -v COLUMN="$COLUMN" -v VALUE="$VALUE" '{if (FNR>1 && ID==$1) {$COLUMN=VALUE}}' $FILE
```

But I think I am doing something wrong with the syntax and I end up getting the whole file printed with no changes.

EXAMPLE:

```
#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
7696581400586|Silva|Manuel|male|1987-08-31|2011-06-07T15:47:05.863+0000|193.126.75.5|Firefox
7696581400608|Li|Jun|female|1983-08-11|2011-05-11T05:20:42.017+0000|27.129.140.209|Chrome
7696581402447|Calvert|Charles|male|1985-09-18|2011-05-27T06:57:05.070+0000|41.51.52.232|Internet Explorer
```

Say the user gives me the inputs 7696581400608 2 Yung. So I replace the field 2 with the name Yung in the line that the id 7696581400608 is placed. So I replace Li with Yung.

Comment: Where is the `ID` awk variable being populated? Right now it's empty at runtime, which almost certainly isn't what you want.

Comment: BTW, consider using lowercase names for your own variables. This keeps your own variables clearly separate from variables with meaning to other components -- including `awk`, but also the shell and UNIX runtime. See [the POSIX environment variable spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html)'s naming conventions given in the fourth paragraph, reserving lower-case names for application use; that applies to regular shell variables too, as a shell variable will overwrite a like-named environment variable.

Comment: the ID is earlier initialized in the code (of course I can't put the whole code in the question but it is initialized inside a while if that helps with identifying scope problems etc) - edit the awk command is placed in the same scope as the variables so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: This is for a project that although it involves awk it revolves around shell scripting and bash and it's something I won't be dealing with in the near future so I just try to get some basic understanding of the language and its techniques. If I decide to or is expected to learn the language in full length I will most certainly follow your advice. Thank you for the book recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v id='7696581400608' -v col=2 -v val='Yung' 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
$1 == id { $col = val } 1' file.csv

#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
7696581400586|Silva|Manuel|male|1987-08-31|2011-06-07T15:47:05.863+0000|193.126.75.5|Firefox
7696581400608|Yung|Jun|female|1983-08-11|2011-05-11T05:20:42.017+0000|27.129.140.209|Chrome
7696581402447|Calvert|Charles|male|1985-09-18|2011-05-27T06:57:05.070+0000|41.51.52.232|Internet Explorer
```

Comment: is the OFS needed? I don't have separators at the end of  the line. It works by the way

Comment: Yes without `OFS`, you will get spaces (default separator) instead of `|` as field separator in the line in which we are making changes.

Comment: yeah I mean FS doesn't do the trick? why we need OFS as well?

Comment: Yes that's what I tried to answer. Without any specific `OFS`, `awk` uses default output field separator i.e. space between columns to construct a complete line. `awk` does it only for lines that are being modified. That's why only 2nd line will be printed with spaces as delimiter without `OFS="|"`

Comment: Oh I get the use of OFS. By the way I did some checking and this command changes only the field at the output. The file remains intact. I want the value to be replaced inside the file also.

Comment: Using gnu-awk you can do: `awk -i inline -v id='7696581400608' -v col=2 -v val='Yung' 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
$1 == id { $col = val } 1' file.csv` otherwise you can do `awk -v id='7696581400608' -v col=2 -v val='Yung' 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
$1 == id { $col = val } 1' file.csv > _tmp_ && mv _tmp_ file.csv`

Comment: I can't help but wonder if there is a simpler approach to this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I've suggested your both possible ways to save the changes back to input file.

Comment: Yeah of course it does. I just hoped for some explaining on the part after the redirection.

Comment: `... > _tmp_ && mv _tmp_ file.csv` is just using a temporary file to save the changes and then renaming temporary file back to original file.

Comment: That clarified it. I wonder if there is a way to make changes using awk directly to the file without "temps" in the way

Comment: In my previous comment, I've already provided you that but that uses `gnu awk`.